# jquery, ajax, create labels array from blogger json feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have the following jQuery (info from here http://www.threelas.com/2012/02/basic-blogger-json-feed-api.html). the problem i am having is returning the labels array which on the website above says is  `json.feed.entry[i].category[];` so how can i return an array?

### http://jsfiddle.net/Pd2cp/

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.blogger.com/feeds/2814965631975331659/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=8',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++){
        var categories = data.feed.entry[i].category[];
        $('#blogContainer').append(categories);
        }
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [edited](http://jsfiddle.net/MUk6S/) your JSFiddle. Here are the changes:

- Use the `callback` parameter in the query with a value of `?` to tell jQuery to assign it's callback here.
- You need to insert something when using brackets (`[]`), or you'll get a syntax error. As you wanted to have the whole Array, I removed the brackets.
- You should cache jQuery calls
- I changed the behavior to loop though all categories and appending it's `term` value to the container.

The remaining "problem" is a comma at the end which can probably be removed.

---

edit: I created a [second fork](http://jsfiddle.net/D9hJA/), which also removes duplicates, sorts all categories and accesses the DOM only once. Besides, there are no overlapping commas.

Comment: i am having one problem, which is separating the lables as to which post they belong to. i,e sepearte the labels which do not belong to the same post... help please

Comment: You have the index of every post, just walk the objects.